# List in list convert to one list?

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

The way I found to convert to one list:

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

result = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        result.append(list1[i][j])

print result
```

and result is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Is there any other way to do this ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just index the list at `0`:

```
result = list1[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
>>> result = list1[0]
>>> result
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

For more than one sublist, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(list1))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just have one item, obviously `list1[0]` will work.

Otherwise in the general case there have been similar questions, e.g. [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

This gave several including including

```
sum(list1, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate lists together directly if you have several of them:

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]

result = []
for sublist in list1:
    result += sublist

print result
```

If it's just a single nested list, iCodez has a faster answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that or use a list comprehension. Both do the same thing, but this is more in the style of python and looks prettier (and works for list of lists), its also called flattening a list:

```
result = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

This will turn

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

into

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

and

```
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

to

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: for list of list of list (and more irregular lists), there are a bunch of methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python